# Unable to make all other checkboxes in the foreach loop to be selected in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm currently having problem wth javascript in my cakephp2 project. What I want to do is make all other checkbox in the foreach loop to be selected and deselected when the "Select all country" is checked/unchecked. I searched around the web but many tutorials I find is quite difficult. Some tipps or example will be great ! I would love to hear from you. 
I have the following code below.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="checkBoxImage">
        <?= $Worldarea['name'] ?>Select all country
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <? foreach ($Worldarea['world']['data'] as $world) {
if (empty ($world['count'])) continue;
$select = array_key_exists($world['id'], $info['query']['area_info']);
?>
  <li>
    <label for="area<?= $world['id'] ?>" alt="<?= $world['area_name'] ?>" 
           <?= ($select) ? 'class="selected"' : '' ?>>
    <input type="checkbox" name="area" value="<?= $world['id'] ?>" id="area<?= $world['id'] ?>" 
           <?= ($sel) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>>
    <span class="checkBoxImage">
      <?= $world['name_display'] ?>
    </span>
  </label>
</li>
<? } ?>
</ul>
```

I think I should do something like the following in the javascript side, but I find it difficult for a beginner in JS to implement the JS side.

```
$(this).parents().eq(1).next().find('li input').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked','');
        $(this).next().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().css('background', 'none');
});
```

Comment: You should post the generated html instead of the php.

Comment: @jeroen is right. The next time you need help with javascript, no need to post the PHP... The resulting html will be way easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the HTML part you provided to make it easy to follow by removing the PHP and making it look like the resulting HTML. Since your PHP is no problem.

First, I added an ID to your checkbox that should select all. That way I could attach an event (onChange) to detect whenever it gets checked or unchecked. In that event, I find all checkboxes in the same list and apply them the checked property according to the current value of the select all box.

```js
$("#checkall").change(function() {
  var is_check = $(this).prop('checked');
  $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', is_check);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkall">
      <span class="checkBoxImage">
        <?= $Worldarea['name'] ?>Select all country
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="area1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="area" value="1" id="area1">
    <span class="checkBoxImage">
      Country name
    </span>
  </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="area2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="area" value="2" id="area2">
    <span class="checkBoxImage">
      Country name
    </span>
  </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="area3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="area" value="3" id="area3">
    <span class="checkBoxImage">
      Country name
    </span>
  </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="area4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="area" value="4" id="area4">
    <span class="checkBoxImage">
      Country name
    </span>
  </label>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add the "id" attribute to your "select all" checkbox. In this example I used "checkbox-ALL".
After that you should change your checkboxes name. Instead of "name", use "name[]" to create an array of checkboxes.
After that you can do:

```
jQuery('#checkbox-ALL').on('click', function () {
    jQuery("input[name*=area]").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```